# Style placeholder texts - input date tag

Tags: html, jquery, css, contact-form-7

If we use input date tag, it will show this format.

[image]

I just want to hide **"dd"** in the date input. So I did this way. And its gone.

```
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field{
    display: none;
}
```

**The problem**

It's showing extra dash **"/"** symbol there. I just want to remove that as well.

I used css first child like this and try to target first child but it's not working.

```
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper ::-webkit-datetime-edit-text:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Any ideas for hiding this? https://jsfiddle.net/mdoty2g9/

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll do it next time.

Comment: ...and why not NOW?

Answer (score 0):

Finlay I found a fix my self. I hide the "/" completely.

```
input::-webkit-datetime-edit-text{
 display: none;
}
```

Then used persudo css this way placing inside the input.

```
input{
 position: relative;
}

input:after {
 content: "/";
 position: absolute;
 left: 60px;
 top: 1px;
}
```

[image]

Problem solved!

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Show a Date Control</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> type="date" is not supported in Safari or Internet Explorer 11 (or earlier).</p>

</body>
</html>
```